# Adding a Space Using Join and List Comprehension

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some html using BeautifulSoup. The page is behind a paywall so I cannot link to it. However, I don't think the html is causing the issue.

When I parse the html using line below the text in div "place-names" does not contain a space so looks like this:

LondonParis instead of London Paris

```
'\n'.join([item.text for item in items.find_all(["div"], {"class": ["svvf", "place-names"]})]).strip()
```

To solve this I thought the following would work:

```
'\n'.join([' '.join(y) for y in [item.text for item in items.find_all(["div"], {"class": ["svvf", "place-names"]})]]).strip()
```

But this returns:

L o n d o n P a r i s

I'm still learning Python and can't work out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you tell me how the outcome of this `[item.text for item in items.find_all(["div"], {"class": ["svvf", "place-names"]})]` look like?

Comment: Please provide an example HTML so everybody could reproduce the issue, it will also improve your question and will lead to more specific answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem lies in `' '.join(y) for y...`.

You're calling `join` on individual strings. Strings are iterators, so it's going to treat each character in the string as its own object to join.

That results in the code putting a space between each of the letters in the string (i.e., "London" becomes "L o n d o n", which is then concatenated with "P a r i s", etc.).

If you take out the extra list comprehension and call the space-join on the list of text items, it should work:

```
# Get items
item_list = items.find_all(["div"], {"class": ["svvf", "place-names"]})

# Get text from each item
item_text_list = [item.text for item in item_list]

# Call join on the item_text_list, not each individual object within that list
item_text_joined = '\n'.join([' '.join(item_text_list)]).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at just 1 iteration. When you use `' '.join(y)`, it's like doing `' '.join('London')`

This will take each character in join with `' '`

```
' '.join('London')
Out[38]: 'L o n d o n'
```

So you are essentionally double looping. You are doing a list comprehension to create the list of `['London', 'Paris']`, then doing `' '.join('London')` and `' 'join('Paris')`

Your first code is actually what you want with:

```
'\n'.join([item.text for item in items.find_all(["div"], {"class": ["svvf", "place-names"]})]).strip()
```

But if you want a space in stead of a new line, change it to:

```
' '.join([item.text for item in items.find_all(["div"], {"class": ["svvf", "place-names"]})]).strip()
```

Look at the code and see the difference:

```
html = '''<div class="svvf">London</div>
<div class="place-names">Paris</div>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

items = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print('With new line:')
print('\n'.join([item.text for item in items.find_all(["div"], {"class": ["svvf", "place-names"]})]).strip())

print('')

print('With the space:')
print(' '.join([item.text for item in items.find_all(["div"], {"class": ["svvf", "place-names"]})]).strip())
```

**Output:**

```
With new line:
London
Paris

With the space:
London Paris
```